# How did the Ship of the Dead survive being torpedoed in the Battle of the Binary Stars?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, star-trek-discovery

In the Star Trek Discovery Episode [S1:E2](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_at_the_Binary_Stars_(episode)) *The Battle at the Binary Stars* - we see a battle between the Klingons and the Federation.

We see the [Ship of the Dead](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sarcophagus) (named for carrying dead warriors on the outside of the ship) receive a Torpedo in the bridge.

In a [later episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Into_the_Forest_I_Go_(episode)), we see the ship still flying around.

The following commentator [writes](https://twitter.com/twittsfromKC/status/930210619080527874):

> I remember Ship of the Dead had a photon torpedo detonate inside its bridge in premiere. Why is it still flying around?

My question is: **How did the Ship of the Dead survive being torpedoed in the Battle of the Binary Stars?**

Comment: The torpedo didn't hit the bridge, it detonated near the engines, badly crippling the ship and leaving it stranded for 6 months. Did you watch episode 4?

Comment: Thanks - that detail escaped me in Ep 4. Could you expand that into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Buther's Knife Cares Not For The Lamb's Cry

Episode 4 shows us the aftermath of the Battle of the Binary Stars. The photon torpedo loaded into the coffin didn't detonate on the bridge of *The Sarcophagus*. Rather, it detonated wherever the coffin ended up, likely a cargo hold of some kind. What's important is that it detonated near the engines, badly crippling the ship of the dead and leaving it unable to move or warp to safety.

With no way to repair the damage to the dilithium processing unit without scavenging Federation ship parts from the Shenzhou, which would go against T'Kuvma's "Pure Klingon" philosophy, Voq, L'Rell and the rest of the ship's crew were stranded for 6 months with a dwindling food supply. Kol took control of the ship after arriving with supplies and using that leverage to turn the crew to his side.

Voq was left in the derelict wreckage of the Shenzhou, and Kol left with *The Sarcophagus*, using it as the new flagship of his house.